div with overflow:clip causing sibling element to take up a lot more space than it should, and the problem gets fixed with float:left?
Edit: For some reason, putting overflow:hidden, overflow:auto, or overflow:scroll on #scrolling-container fixes the problem, but if I put overflow:clip or just remove the overflow attribute, it starts behaving weirdly again...
Edit: changing overflow:clip to overflow:hidden on container-outer also works
I have this div and this p here
<div id="container-outer" class="container-outer-collapsed blueborder">
    <div id="tax-deduction-calculator-container" class="blueborder tax-calculator-hidden">
        <div id="scrolling-container">
            <div id="tax-deduction-calculator" style="transition:0.2s;"> </div>
            <div id="formula"> </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<p>
    <img src="my-url">
</p>

With the following CSS (I know the top and left do not affect static elements, they are only there for a CSS transition):
#tax-deduction-calculator-container.tax-calculator-hidden {
    margin-left: 88px;
}
#tax-deduction-calculator-container.tax-calculator-hidden {
    width: 150px !important;
    height: 50px !important;
    position: relative;
}
#tax-deduction-calculator-container {
    background-color: white;
    position: relative;
    border-width: 4px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 600px;
    margin-left: calc((100% - 400px) / 2);
    overflow: clip;
    transition: 0.2s;
    /*transform: translateZ(0);*/
}
#container-outer.container-outer-collapsed {
    width: 150px;
    height: 50px;
    overflow: clip;
    border-radius: 20px;
    position: static !important;
    left: 100px;
    top: 50px;
}
#container-outer {
    position: fixed;
    line-height: normal !important;
}
.blueborder {
    border-color: rgb(0, 183, 255);
    border-style: solid;
}
#scrolling-container {
    width: 800px;
}
#scrolling-container > div {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

#tax-deduction-calculator, #formula {
    font-family: gotham, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: rgb(0, 153, 204);
    text-align: center;
    height: 600px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    width: 400px;
    transform: translateZ(0);
    overflow-y: auto;
}

And here is the display I am getting in Google Chrome with inspect element


Here is a zoomed out version:

However if I add float:left to the container-outer div, I get the desired result:

What exactly is going on here?
Edit: the additional space seem to be equal to the height of #tax-deduction-calculator and #formula
Edit: forgot to add a div. Also I tried placing the #container-outer div somewhere else, and #tax-deduction-calculator and #formula are still taking up space

IIRC, the #container-outer div is still taking up space equal to the height of its children elements (#tax-deduction-calculator and #formula), even though their content is clipped.

not really, inspect element is showing that it's the <p> that's somehow taking up the space of #tax-deduction-calculator and #formula even though it's they are children elements of another element

@Ghost I tried placing it somewhere else and it does seem like #tax-deduction-calculator and #formula are somehow taking up space. Added it to the edit, thanks
